# how to save more then one HTML forms values in a single PHP file without using SQL

Tags: php, html, forms

I've two different form on two different HTML pages, e.g test.html and home.html, the single php file is server.php 
the code in "test.html" is

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="server.php" method="post">
<input type=text name=day>
<input type=submit name=sub value=sub>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

the code in "home.html" is

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="server.php" method="post">
<input type=text name=text1>
<input type=submit name=submit value=submit>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

code in php file is

```
<?php
if($_POST['sub']){
$start_day=$_REQUEST['day'];

header("Location: home.html");
}
if($_POST['submit']){
    $a=$_REQUEST['text1'];
    echo $a;
    echo $start_day;
}
```

suppose I'm on "test.html" form and I click on submit it take me on "home.html" after storing "test.html" value into $start_day variable, when I fill second form and click sub it just show the $a variable value. why not it show the $start_day value ? why it is not working ? please give me a right solution that how I can do this..
I hope you people will understand my problem, that what i want to do..
I also try session

```
<?php
if($_POST['sub']){
$start_day=$_REQUEST['day'];
session_start();
$_SESSION['start_day']=$start_day;

header("Location: home.html");
}
if($_POST['submit']){
    $a=$_REQUEST['text1'];
    echo $a;
    session_start();
    $start_day=$_SESSION['start_day'];
    echo $start_day;

}
?>
```

but it still make wornning  like "33
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\xampp\3T Scheduler\server.php:16) in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\xampp\3T Scheduler\server.php on line 17
---select a day---"

Comment: You're posting two times, the first post value gets lost in the second submit. Try to use a session?

Comment: You aren't storing anything. Each time you run the script, the variables are instantiated and then killed, they do not persist unless you write them to globals or superglobals

Comment: can you please give me an example on session that how i can use session Lars Mertens